# Registering Mediator source generator, Ambigious call between mediator Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, .net, mediator

I am trying to register the following .NET implementation of the Mediator pattern using the source generators feature introduced in .NET [mediatrsourcegenerator](https://github.com/martinothamar/Mediator).

I installed the required packages
**dotnet add package Mediator.SourceGenerator --version 2.0.*
dotnet add package Mediator.Abstractions --version 2.0.***

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
//DI
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDocumentService, DocumentService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICacheService, CacheService>();


builder.Services.AddScoped<IValidationService, ValidationService>();

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddMediator(options =>
{
    options.ServiceLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient;
});
```

I get the following error when building application even though the source generator successfully generates the file.

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MediatorDependencyInjectionExtensions.AddMediator(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Mediator.MediatorOptions>)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MediatorDependencyInjectionExtensions.AddMediator(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Mediator.MediatorOptions>)**

I have not got package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection installed at all, I tried to add it then build(did not work) and then remove it and build(did not work) but the problem persist so it has got nothing to do with that.

I tried something like

```
builder.Services.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MediatorDependencyInjectionExtensions.AddMediator(options =>
{
    options.ServiceLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient;
});
```

but that doesnt work, also restarted VS.  how to resolve this ambiguity. The error message is a bit confusing it looks like the reference is completely identical, someone has ever experienced a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this from Mediator GitHub readme, this fixed this issue for me:

> 3. Usage and abstractions ... You install the **source generator package** *into your edge/outermost project* (i.e. ASP.NET Core application,
>    Background worker project), and then use the **Mediator.Abstractions**
>    package *wherever you define message types and handlers*.

Comment: thank you!!, yea the source generator package was not installed in the edge/outermost project but was getting that from some sharing library